# TypeScript Generic Function Arguments Based on Type Key/Value(type)

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, typescript-generics

So basically, the code below: I'm trying to create a function of which the first argument is a string value which is restricted to the type's key names and the second argumenta callback which can only return that type key's type (ie. if you pass 'str' as the first argument, you can only return a string value in the callback)

Here's what I have so far, which works until I create a function expression and pass it as the second argument:

```
    type Events = {
        title: string;
        cost: number;
    }

    type KeyType<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K]; // look up the type's key's type..


    type CallBack<T extends keyof Events> = (...args: any[]) => KeyType<Events, T>;


    const subscribers: Map<keyof Events, CallBack<keyof Events>[]> = new Map();

    const subscribe = <T extends keyof Events>(eventName: T, callback: CallBack<T>) => {

    const lookup = subscribers.get(eventName)
        if (!lookup) {
            subscribers.set(eventName, [callback])
        } else {
            lookup.push(callback)
        }

    }

    subscribe('title', () => { return "hello" }) // ok


    const returnString: CallBack<'title'> = () => { return 'one' };
    const returnNumber: CallBack<'cost'> = () => { return 789789789 };

    const returnNumberInfer = () => { return 1 };

    subscribe('title', returnString) // ok..
    subscribe('cost', returnNumber) // ok....

    subscribe('title', returnNumber) // shouldn't be okay but it is..
    subscribe<'title'>('title', returnNumber) // remove inferrence and works, but not intuitive..

    subscribe('title', returnNumberInfer) // when not typed to a CallBack<T> it works..

    // inline delcaration, everything works great.
    subscribe('cost', () => { return 789789789 }) // ok
    subscribe('title', () => { return 789789789 }) // error
```

Comment: ① Note that `KeyType` is already a type in the dom lib so this conflicts unless you're in a module.  Since you're just defining it as `T[K]` can you just remove it so this is more of a [mre]? ② TS doesn't have a native way to say "don't infer a type param from this location" as per [ms/TS#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) but there are various ways to emulate this, such as adding another type param, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJ1Ekm). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Ahh, clever - you're basically stating that 'KC' can only ever be the string literal of 'K' in the constraints of the subscribe function? I think this write-up satisfies the question. Thank you.

Comment: The existing answer below has the same effect and also mentions ms/TS#14829 so I don't think I'll write another one

Answer (score 0):

Since there are two inference sites for `T` it ended up picking the `T` that would satisfy both locations.

You could use the `NoInfer` type (from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546)) to force typescript to only use the `eventName` location:

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];
const subscribe = <T extends keyof Events>(eventName: T, callback: CallBack<NoInfer<T>>) => {
    // ...

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4FgBQ6YE8zDgUQDdgA7GAZzgF5F0564YBLGAG2AC45yYomSA5gG46DAMYQeXEgFcAtgCNgUEWlRpsuOAGlgWACo5gAHn0AaHXFAxSAE0oBrPRABmcfQD5q7gNraAukJwAPTBcKwQEA5wMmCMABZ4msAA5I56aYxGAHTZ6PkaRnAAwgCGrKwAQqViDqZWIDYk9nBOWK4ExGTkXjQAFLnZpVAC5FylJFg+-gCU1F66BkbGRKQUFp6qBRIkPNwyCuRifEpQY3AAsqVgxm0dq90WZRXVtbfObg8UHtO9cCTAADul2ufRmW0KWgAchAAJIkFzKUx-Hz6fyohpNFoTLBwAD8cAADHBpMBiFBAugdntyAcjic8DR6tY7Ol2p8ut8+mS1lDSnJOO4LGJyqwFDUHFxnlUJcYYfDEVBkR45lQvAgCgw4NT4BEorFvLTDscmKdyNkBMAYNzOXyBTNRPQmG4+gBCPUOWJzDVoLVao3003Kc3kK023n84AWHwiiri2qzR1wJBWVih2i+v30D2xbJgGTkeJ9WNiiUOzP0dToKtoAMmpR9FLMNipCxg+aIOBQK0yKAkOAAIkSFQgA+Tc1CcCiBSpEF28G7MF7JAAyrx+AIpaLXnUmyx2Ck-u21Z3F8u4Ck56lk6odV2e32ofJTluXrKUhIeIfvMf1fel32cAAOwABwAJygRB4E3tsc57Gej7PsoCrKD+qp-gh-YAIwwRgtZ0vWwCNs2B4WJha58IIE5hFEuToHWDKNp+MApGRD4kE+ijKNRU4OIMeR4QxQbEfurb-sunGnDxhYQDIrC2CQTZwEovGlLiCgyPALBwEw5oCUJSjGHuLaHiJJlsQBHFIVAPHdnIEDEDpCLKN2JBiHgEy2HAgLQA45AWBp8AkBAWlkDILBMMQdGCQRjHGaR4mIVxUAoTZIRhICiT9sF8DJF5MAQHApQlNusqeDp8A+VAfnRegk78Kw-B4LYwCsCKUClMwc4WDyUBYDA8Qbt5vmUAI3adfpsXCR+kgsW26GnuxwHgZBkHjulvH0VNDbxWJv6LZZy1Qcd62Ti50BAA)

Comment: Could you elaborate exactly what's happening in the `NoInfer` type?

Comment: ps. I need a bit of help here, haha. I understand none of that type lol